# Oracle Database optimization with INDEXing

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, query-optimization

I have three tables (student, faculty and grades) and I want to optimize following query with indexing some of columns or with the other words creating secondary physical structures. My query is this:

```
select * from STUDENT S, FACULTY F
where S.facul=F.facul AND S.grade NOT IN (
select overall from grades G
where overall > 500 and overall < 1900);
```

I can't use like "`where S.grade <= 500 OR S.grade >= 1900`", because in the GRADES table there are lot of other options which I will use later. So it is important selecting from GRADES table.

I am a beginner on Oracle SQL, so please, help me and be more specific.

Comment: What other options do you have in the `grades.overall` column? The column should be NUMBER data type (if not, that's a big mistake - if the grades are SUPPOSED to be numeric), so the only other thing you must be careful with is NULL in some rows. But that can be treated correctly in the outer query, too,

Answer (score 3):

This is your query (rewritten a bit):

```
select *
from STUDENT S join
     FACULTY F
     on S.facul = F.facul 
where S.grade NOT IN (select g.overall
                      from grades G
                      where overall > 500 and overall < 1900
                     );
```

The `not in` is really useless.  You can write this as:

```
select *
from STUDENT S join
     FACULTY F
     on S.facul = F.facul 
where S.grade <= 500 OR S.grade >= 1900 ;
```

Then, you want indexes.  I think `STUDENT(grade, facul)` and `FACTULRY(facul)` should work.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it and compare both of prices. Thank you again

Comment: Dear @gordon-linoff, I can't use like "where S.grade <= 500 OR S.grade >= 1900", because in the `GRADES` table there are lot of other options which I will use later. So it is important selecting from GRADES table

Comment: @RasulbekAbdurasulov . . . If you have another question, then you should ask it as *another* question.  It is only reasonable to expect people to answer the question you did ask.  Changing this question would be rude, because it would probably invalidate this answer, which in turn attracts downvotes.